# How to reference a Twig expression inside an expression

Tags: twig, shopware

I'm trying to reference a Twig expression inside another expression:

```
{{ dbquery('name', 'product_manufacturer_translation', {'product_manufacturer_id =' lineItem.payload.manufacturerId} ) }}
```

Here, lineItem.payload.manufacturerId is the Twig expression I'm trying to put into the dbquery - but this does not work. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Edit: this query does not yield a result. What I would expect is a product manufacturer name, based on the product manufacturer ID. The manufacturerId experssion itself, when used on its own, does yield a result. I know there is a database record that should match this query, too.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: this does not yield a result. I expect that it is due to the fact that I did not put in the expression the correct way.

Comment: No it does seems correct, u'r getting an error?

Comment: I'm trying to set-up an order confirmation mail on Shopware 6. Unfortunately, the platform does not give any feedback on templates - it just does not work. I can see from the logging the mail is not even sent, which is due to the fact because it breaks when compiling.

Comment: Nothing in the error logs?

Comment: Nope - at least not the ones I have access to (in the Shopware platform). I've now found a workaround and have a developer build a custom solution. Thanks for you help, all.

Comment: @Bowtie would u mind shearing your solution? This could be helpful if someone tries to do the same :)

Comment: Of course! My goal with the query was to find the name of the associated manufacturer of a certain product, so I could show this in an order confirmation email. My workaround is now to take the manufacturer ID (which is an attribute that I do have), and then go through a superlong list of if/else statements to match the ID of a product and then print the name. Hope this helps!